# Numpy cannot be accessed on Jupyter. Is it a problem with the path and how do I fix that?

Tags: python, numpy, path, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

This is probably a very basic question but I have not been able to solve it for some time.

My goal is to start using Python with Jupyter Notebook for data analytics.

I first downloaded Python 3.7 on OSx10.95. Then tried to download Anaconda, which failed a few times. Then I downloaded Miniconda and used Wing101. After that I could download Anaconda. However, I did not get Anaconda navigator to work.

Then I started using Jupyter Notebook from terminal. It works but there are a number of problems:

In Jupyter when I try to import pandas and numpy I get an error:

```
--------

<ipython-input-1-baf368f80de7> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
     17 if missing_dependencies:
     18     raise ImportError(
---> 19         "Missing required dependencies{0}".format(missing_dependencies))
     20 del hard_dependencies, dependency, missing_dependencies
     21 

ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

----------
```

Numpy is installed though, but it is probably in the wrong place.

Another problem is that the Anaconda and Python files are all over my computer:

The Anaconda navigator is at:

```
/anaconda3
```

Pip 3.7 is at:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/
```

Numpy is at:

```
/Users/lsluyser/Downloads/ENTER/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/
```

Jupyter files are at:

```
/Users/lsluyser/Downloads/ENTER/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

and also at:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

My question is:
What is the desired organization of the program files and how do I achieve this?
Should I move all files from Downloads to another folder?
Should numpy be put under `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages?`
Can the fact that Anaconda navigator does not work have to do with its location?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Miniconda, which is a smaller alternative to Anaconda.  Even if you don't, you should download the packages you need, such as numpy, from 
[Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=numpy), which should put the files in proper location.

Generally [on Windows] the packages should be in folder C:\Users\<>\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages and verify the environment variable has necessary paths.

Comment: Thank you, I completely deleted everything and installed Miniconda again. Saves a lot of files.. What do you mean with the last sentence: "verify the environement variable has necessary paths?"

Comment: @Lotte here's a good explanation of environment variable and paths:  [What are path and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: thank you I understand now a lot better what is meant with path etc. Unfortunately we are still not able to get rid of that fact that Jupyter notebook expects a file that does not exist: '/Users/lsluyser/anaconda3/bin/python3

Comment: When I removed in terminal the paths and bash_profiles that still referred to Anaconda (although that was removed and Miniconda installed after that), jupyter notebook did not start up anymore in that session.

Comment: Have you checked this, perhaps?  [What to do when things go wrong — Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html) .  If it still doesn't work, you should try launching from command prompt in a terminal window:   >>jupyter notebook    >>python3  do they work?

Comment: if it still doesn't work, then please post your PATH variables and current folders paths for the Conda installation.

Comment: (base) air-van-lotte:~ lsluyser$ conda activate venv1
(venv1) air-van-lotte:~ lsluyser$ echo $PATH
/Users/lsluyser/Downloads/ENTER/bin:/Users/lsluyser/miniconda3/envs/venv1/bin:/Users/lsluyser/miniconda3/condabin:~/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/Users/lsluyser/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
(venv1) air-van-lotte:~ lsluyser$

Comment: Dear SanV, I have indeed looked in the Jupyter Notebook information and on all kinds of other places. As you can see above, the path keeps referring to anaconda3, although that was removed and I now use miniconda.

Comment: Also it seemed that my bash_profile was polluted with code left by Anaconda3. But I do not know how to reproduce that anymore. When typing: 'open ~/bash_profile' I get the message that there is none.

Comment: I hope you can help with the last bits

Comment: Lotte, I've found Jupyter Ntbk to be a great tool but I use it on Windows machine.  For me installation was quite straightforward because I stuck with their instructions quite closely.  I am not familiar with Macs.  However, I suggest perhaps trying install on a new machine, if possible, and using Miniconda.  Note that even with that install you'll see some entries "Anaconda" because Mini- is just a subset of the Ana-.  It is difficult for me to offer additional ideas other than online links because of unfamiliarity with Macs and inability to know the exact details of your situation & errors.

Comment: OK @SanV thank you, I appreciate your help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to work in Python, you will soon realize the need for creating multiple python **virtual environments** on your computer.
This is because, when working in Python:

1. You will constantly run into situations that require you to install, upgrade, or downgrade some new module.
2. Each such install, upgrade, or downgrade could have some unwanted side-effect (something that was working earlier, stops working after the change).
3. By creating multiple virtual environments, you will be able to perform such installs, upgrades or downgrades within a specific environment, with no risk of affecting your other environments.

Tools such as Anaconda and Miniconda make it easy for you to create and manage such virtual environments.

Under the hood, the creation and management of the virtual environments is probably not much more than setting some environment variables.

I found [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c) to be a good intro to the concept.

For your problem, yes, most likely your problem with `numpy` can be solved by suitably setting environment variables, but I would suggest not to attempt that.

Instead, use Anaconda or Miniconda to create an environment, and within that environment, use Anaconda or Miniconda to install numpy. You will of course will be prompted about any pre-requisites that may be needed for numpy.

Comment: thank you, very useful to know about the environments.